# Fabric.js - Exclude specific object from being saved using JSON.stringify();

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

In my project I'm creating an object which is used as a source for cloning.

I want to **not** save that source object when I'm running `JSON.stringify(canvas);` because I'm using undo/redo functions and want the cloned objects to be rendered back without the source object being there.

Is there a way to tell fabric to ignore saving a specific object as part of the `stringify` method? I know I could simply delete the source object before saving it, but I don't want to do that for various reasons.

Comment: You could make a shallow copy of all the properties you _do_ want to stringify.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What's a shallow copy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in the fabricjs docs there is a property for the Object class calles 'excludeFromExport'.

Once set to true it should do exactly what you want.

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#excludeFromExport